Download Parallel Embedded Resource In Blazemeter
Not getting any option to download parallel embedded resource in blazemeter.
I am trying to do performance test and running my test in blazmeter for single uer and single iteration. The test required web pages in that i want to download parallel embedded resource but i am not getting option for this.

BlazeMeter is a PaaS which uses Taurus framework under the hood.
Depending on the underlying load or automation test tool the instructions for enabling parallel download of the embedded resources will differ.
For default executor which is Apache JMeter it's up to you to configure JMeter to download embedded resources. If this is your case - add HTTP Request Defaults configuration element to your JMeter Test Plan and under "Advanced" tab you will find configuration options like whether to download embedded resources, how many threads to use, which URLs to include/exclude, etc.

More information: JMeter Web Testing: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses
